# flutter InAppWebView: how to show local html fine on IOS

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I am trying to use InAppWebView on my Flutter project. I created a plugin and I want to use InAppWebView inside my plugin  actually.

this is my page:

```
class _FormIosState extends State<FormIos> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();
  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  InAppWebViewSettings settings = InAppWebViewSettings(
      isInspectable: kDebugMode,
      useOnDownloadStart: true,
      javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true,
      javaScriptEnabled: true,
      useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true);
  String url = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              InAppWebView(
                key: webViewKey,
                initialFile: "packages/myPlugin/src/web/index.html",
                // initialUrlRequest:
                //     URLRequest(url: WebUri('https://flutter.dev')),
               
                initialUserScripts: UnmodifiableListView<UserScript>([]),
                initialSettings: settings,
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                  webViewController = controller;
                },
                onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
                  debugPrint("onLoadStart");
                },
                onPermissionRequest: (controller, request) async {
                  debugPrint("onPermission request");
                  return PermissionResponse(
                      resources: request.resources,
                      action: PermissionResponseAction.GRANT);
                },
                shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                  debugPrint("shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
                  return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                },
                onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                  debugPrint("onLoadStop");
                  setState(() {
                    this.url = url.toString();
                  });
                },
                onReceivedError: (controller, request, error) {
                  debugPrint("onReceivedError");
                },
                onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, isReload) {
                  debugPrint("onUpdateVisitedHistory");
                },
                onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                  debugPrint("onConsoleMessage");
                  print(consoleMessage);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I have a simple html inside my plugin lib/src/web, but when I am running an example inside my plugin on IOS and I want to show my index HTML nothing happens, No error and no one of all callbacks did call.

But if I comment initialFile: "packages/myPlugin/src/web/index.html", and I uncomment

```
initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri('https://flutter.dev')),
```

web view works and I can see flutter site on IOS.

this is my simple html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><title>Navigation Delegate Example</title></head>
<body>
<p>
    The navigation delegate is set to block navigation to the youtube website.
</p>
<ul>
    <ul><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">https://www.youtube.com/</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a></ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I also put my HTML inside my plugin root assets folder :

assets:

- assets/
- assets/web

and I changed initialFile: "packages/mypackagename/assets/web/index.html"

nothing happend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a dummy issue. I am writing here maybe help others.

```
assets:
 - assets/web/ // <-- count two spaces from start
```

in my plugin yaml file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `initialUrlRequest` use `initialFile` and pass the path to your asset. Make sure to add this file to `assets:` in your `pubspec.yaml`.

If your file is in `lib/src/web/index.html`, then you should use the same path in both pubspec and `initialFile`.

https://inappwebview.dev/docs/intro/#load-files-inside-the-assets-folder

Comment: my friend , I did it  initialFile: "packages/myPlugin/src/web/index.html",

Comment: Yes, sorry, I updated the answer. You don't need the `packages/myPlugin` part if it's asset in the same package and you do need to pass the full relative path (including `lib/`)

Comment: BTW, I recommend not keeping assets in `lib/` as it's a directory intended for Dart files. You should put them e.g. in `assets/` in your app directory :)

Comment: But my asset is not in same package.is  inside my flutter plugin, not in the main project, so I used packages/myPlugin/assets/web/index.html, but still nothing

Comment: Does this plugin have `assets/web/index.html` in its `assets` in plugin's pubspec?

Comment: yes it does ,I have assets in my plugin also

Comment: https://postimg.cc/sBhn160G this is image

Comment: Is `assets.web` just your IDE showing nested directories, or is it really an `assets.web/index.html` path?

Comment: just ide shows, It is a asset folder, inside it, there is a web folder

Comment: I am using this also : onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                  webViewController = controller;
                  await webViewController!.loadFile(
                      assetFilePath:
                          "packages/mypackagename/assets/web/index.html");
                } I am getting this error  ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(WebViewChannelDelegate, packages/mypackagename/assets/web/index.html asset file cannot be found!, null, null)

Comment: https://postimg.cc/5jxZkJRP here

Comment: I found the issue